# yii-dbmigrations does not have a method named "performTransactional"

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a new problem using the latest version of yii-dbmigration, when I run the migration the console shows the message below and the migration not work.

```
$ ./protected/yiic migrate
Migrations directory: protected/migrations/

=== Applying: m20110123200901_create_eav_table =================================
ERROR: m20110123200901_create_eav_table does not have a method named "performTransactional".
```

The code of migration is:

```
<?php

class m20110123200901_create_eav_table extends CDbMigration {

    public function up() {
      $t = $this->newTable('eav');
      $t->primary_key('id');
      $t->integer('section_id');
      $t->integer('entry_id');
      $t->integer('field_id');
      $t->string('attribute');
      $t->text('value');
      $t->datetime('created_at');
      $t->datetime('updated_at');
      $this->addTable($t);
    }

    public function down() {
      $this->removeTable('eav');
    }

}
```

Anyone know what happens?

Thanks.

### Edited

Hi guys, 
I found the problem, but I don't know the solution.

The problem occur on the Yii v1.1.7-dev, when I'm using a another version  (like v1.1.5-dev) the migrations works right.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I found the problem and the solution.

I was using the yii-dbmigration extension, and the yii has a implementation of migrations since v1.1.6, so the two versions were conflicting when I was run the migrations.

The solutions is, uninstall the extension and use the new native migration.

A personal opinion about the yii native migration feature and the yii extension db-migration is that the second likes more easy and elegant to work because it has a great oop implementation on up/down method.

Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I never used the extension, but I am glad that similar functionality has been rolled in to the core, it is a very good feature. Feel free to mark your answer as the correct one! Cheers